# MS CRM 2011 rollup 12 "Syntax error" when run any report

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, syntax-error

MS CRM 2011 rollup 12 shows "Syntax error" when run any report

**Form IE9:**

```
Microsoft Dynamics CRM Error Report Contents

<CrmScriptErrorReport>
 <ReportVersion>1.0</ReportVersion>
  <ScriptErrorDetails>
   <Message>Syntax error</Message>
   <Line>243</Line>
   <URL>/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx?action=filter&helpID=Account%20Distribution.rdl&id=%7b5E8B4D88-D520-E111-9657-00155DFEFD04%7d</URL>
   <PageURL>/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx?action=filter&helpID=Account%20Distribution.rdl&id=%7b5E8B4D88-D520-E111-9657-00155DFEFD04%7d</PageURL>
   <Function></Function>
   <CallStack>
   </CallStack>
  </ScriptErrorDetails>
  <ClientInformation>
   <ClientName>Web</ClientName>
   <ClientTime>2013-02-12T21:05:09</ClientTime>
  </ClientInformation>
  <ServerInformation>
    <CRMVersion>5.0.9690.3236</CRMVersion>
  </ServerInformation>
</CrmScriptErrorReport>
```

**From Chrome:**

```
Microsoft Dynamics CRM Error Report Contents

<CrmScriptErrorReport>
  <ReportVersion>1.0</ReportVersion>
  <ScriptErrorDetails>
   <Message>Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .</Message>
   <Line>243</Line>
   <URL>/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx?action=filter&helpID=Account%20Distribution.rdl&id=%7b5E8B4D88-D520-E111-9657-00155DFEFD04%7d</URL>
   <PageURL>/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx?action=filter&helpID=Account%20Distribution.rdl&id=%7b5E8B4D88-D520-E111-9657-00155DFEFD04%7d</PageURL>
   <Function></Function>
   <CallStack>
   </CallStack>
  </ScriptErrorDetails>
  <ClientInformation>
   <ClientName>Web</ClientName>
   <ClientTime>2013-02-12T21:13:40</ClientTime>
  </ClientInformation>
  <ServerInformation>
    <CRMVersion>5.0.9690.3236</CRMVersion>
  </ServerInformation>
</CrmScriptErrorReport>
```

Works before update (on rollup 11). Stop working right after update (rollup 12).

- On-Premise single server deployment.
- Windows Server 2008 R2
- SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2

Run under admin user

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved.

I've manually changed viewer.aspx file and it was not updated by rollup12. So I just deleted this file and run update again. And it works now.